# How can I find out what happened to my Debian box?

Tags: linux, debian

I have an old PC lying around which I've installed Debian 6.0 on.  Last night I was trying to SSH in and it wouldn't respond so I pressed the reset button.  How can I find out what happened to it?  It seems fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your computer is usually stable, check for hardware problems, especially with the RAM (i.e. install `memtest86+` and choose memtest at the boot prompt), but also with disks (disk errors sometimes crash the filesystem code; install `smartmontools` and run `smartctl -a /dev/sda`). If the problem was gradual, you may find something in the kernel logs (`/var/log/kern.log`), but often the crash happens too brutally for anything to be written to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the .1 logs is always a good place to start.

Use `iptraf` to see if your machine makes any suspisious connections (if someone got/has unauthorized access).

Run a `rkhunter` scan:
`aptitude install rkhunter`
`rkhunter --update`
`rkhunter --check`

And should it ever happen again, attach a monitor and see what the console says :)

Comment: On a side note: If someone even remotely capable got into your system and shut you out there probably wont be any trace of it.

Answer (score 0):

By this -

> How can I find out what happened to it?

I presume you want to know what happened during your failed attempt at SSH!

One place to look into will be `/var/log`. Something like `grep -ir ssh /var/log/*` should give you the SSH related log entries.